# How to compute div&curl of volume velocity field with Helmholtz decomposition if velocity field is known?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, limits

I ran into an interesting mathematical problem that is the result of the use of infinitesimal vector calculus in relation to the Helmholtz theorem and the vector LaPlace operator. What is very interesting is that the Helmholtz decomposition is hidden within the vector LaPlace operator and this can be used to define potential fields. For the general case:

The terms in the definition for the vector Laplacian can be negated and equaled to zero to obtain the vector Laplace equation:

$-∇^2 = -∇(∇·) + ∇×(∇×) = 0,$

and then the terms in this identity can be written out to define a vector field for each of these:

$ = ∇×$

$Φ = ∇⋅$

$ = ∇× = ∇×(∇×)$

$ = −∇Φ = −∇(∇⋅)$

And, since the curl of the gradient of any twice-differentiable scalar field $Φ$ is always the zero vector $(∇×(∇Φ)=0)$, and the divergence of the curl of any vector field $ \mathbf A$ is always zero as well $(∇⋅(∇×A)=0)$, we can establish that $ \mathbf E$ is curl-free and $ \mathbf B$ is divergence-free, and we can write:

$∇×= 0$

$∇⋅= 0$

As can be seen from this, the vector Laplacian establishes a Helmholtz decomposition of any given vector field  into an irrotational or curl free component  and a divergenceless component , along with associated potential fields Φ and , all from a single equation c.q. operator:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition

"In physics and mathematics, in the area of vector calculus, Helmholtz's theorem, also known as the fundamental theorem of vector calculus, states that any sufficiently smooth, rapidly decaying vector field in three dimensions can be resolved into the sum of an irrotational (curl-free) vector field and a solenoidal (divergence-free) vector field; this is known as the Helmholtz decomposition or Helmholtz representation."

It may be interesting to note that the vector LaPlace operator is the 3D generalization of the 1D second derivative or curvature, so in 1D the LaPlace operator is simply: $ \delta^2 / \delta x^2$.

For fluid dynamics, we can use this decomposition to define a vector and a scalar potential for the velocity field, analogous to the electrodynamic domain like this:

$ \mathbf v = -∇Φ + ∇×$

$ = −∇Φ$

$ = ∇×$

From this, we can do an analysis of the units of measurement, since the curl, grad and div operators all have a unit of measurement in per meter[/m]. Since $ \mathbf v$, $E$ and $B$ all have a unit of measurement of velocity in meters per second [$m/s$], we obtain a unit of measurement in cubic meters per second [$m^3/s$] for the primary field $ \mathbf F$, thus describing a volumetric flow field, similar to the volumetric flow rate:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volumetric_flow_rate

"Volumetric flow rate is defined by [...] the flow of volume of fluid V through a surface per unit time t."

It seems the volumetric flow vector $\mathbf F$ can be defined as the flow velocity vector $\mathbf v$ times an area $ \mathbf A$ perpendicular to $\mathbf v$ with a surface proportional to $h^2$ square meters [$m^2$], with $h$ the physical length scale in meters [$m$].

For finite difference or discrete vector calculus methods, such as used in FDTD simulation software, $h$ denotes the spacing of the discretization grid, which may be variable or constant. This leads to the conclusion that $F \neq 0$ for any $ \mathbf v \neq 0$ and any $h>0$ and therefore when using discrete mathematics $ \mathbf F$ exists and according to the Helmholtz theorem it is uniquely defined by the two potential fields.

Now here's the problem: when we take the limit for $h \to 0$, which we do with infinitesimal notation, we obtain $ \mathbf F=0$, which cannot be correct for any field whereby $\mathbf v \neq 0$, so what we find is that there is a limit to the applicability of the Helmholtz decomposition when using infinitesimal calculus and that in fact **the Helmholtz decomposition does not always hold**. This needs to be worked around.

However, if $ \mathbf v$ is known and $ \mathbf F$ can be defined as $ \mathbf v$ times an area $ \mathbf A$ perpendicular to $\mathbf v$, it seems it should be possible to compute the curl and divergence of $ \mathbf F$ from this definition and thus come to a completely closed system of potential theory, whereby all fields are uniquely defined and can be analytically solved, except the volumetric flow field $ \mathbf F$ itself.

So, the question is: ***how do we do that?***

Finally, it should be noted that if this can be solved, this has tremendous consequences for the analysis of fluid dynamics problems, such as weather forecasting, the study of vortex behavior, aircraft design, oceanography, etc., etc.  This is because currently, the potential fields have been defined slightly different and without the use of separate E and B components. Because the Helmholtz decomposition allows these components to be independently computed after which superposition may be applied, the definitions shared above undoubtedly have important applications within fluid dynamics, even if no answer to the question can be found because recourse can be taken to discrete mathematics as is done anyway with numerical analysis techniques.

In case you are interested in how I ran into this problem, see here:

[https://www.researchgate.net/publication/341931087_Revision_of_Maxwell's_Equations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/341931087_Revision_of_Maxwell%27s_Equations)

**Update**:

I've made some progress in answering this question:

What **F** represents is actually one of the questions. Because the curl, div and grad operators all have a unit of measurement in per meter [$/m$], all we know for certain is that **F** has a unit of measurement in [$m^3/s$] and that it's a vector, so one is tempted to conclude it represents a volumetric flow, similar to the volumetric flow rate but represented by a vector rather than a scalar.

The problem with this is that in reality, no such thing as a point without a volume actually exists, while with infinitesimal calculus that's exactly how a point is described. So, when one considers each "point" in the vector field to have a volume, as you do with discrete mathematics, **F** can be computed and represents the volume of flow going trough your "point volume" per second. With infinitesimal calculus, the volume of your "point" goes to zero and that is why **F** cannot be computed. It seems to be undefined, which is very interesting from a mathematical point of view, because the Helmholtz decomposition also says (slightly edited):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition#Fields_with_prescribed_divergence_and_curl

"Let **A** be a solenoidal vector field and Φ a scalar field on $R^3$ which are sufficiently smooth and which vanish faster than $1/r^2$ at infinity. Then there exists a vector field **F** such that:

$∇⋅F=Φ$ and $∇×F=A$,

and if additionally, the vector field F vanishes as r → ∞, then F is unique."

This is very confusing. I first thought we needed to go to discrete mathematics, and then I though: No, the solution F=0 is unique and that's very nice.

Until I realied that both the divergence as well as the curl of such an F are, well, zero. :(

So, I have some rewriting to do of my paper and this time I'd like to do it correctly.

The idea is that because both the two potential fields as well as the three velocity fields can be evaluated and **F** seems to be a multiplication of **v** times some (infinitesimal) surface area $\delta S$, it should be possible to compute the curl **F** and div **F** from the velocity field **v**, even though **F** itself cannot be computed for a point that has no volume.

Conceptually, this would involve re-arranging the integrals involved in the calculation, but I haven't figured out how to do that yet. But it is interesting to consider the divergence theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem

"the divergence theorem states that the surface integral of a vector field over a closed surface, which is called the flux through the surface, is equal to the volume integral of the divergence over the region inside the surface."

And the Kelvin–Stokes theorem:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin–Stokes_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Stokes_theorem)

"Given a vector field, the theorem relates the integral of the curl of the vector field over some surface, to the line integral of the vector field around the boundary of the surface."

So, it seems that **F** is "the volume integral of the divergence" over a certain volume plus "the integral of the curl of the vector field" over the surface area that encloses said volume. However, Kelvin-Stokes theorem does not handle a closed surface, so we'd have to look at a more general theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem

"The fundamental theorem of calculus states that the integral of a function f over the interval [a, b] can be calculated by finding an antiderivative F of f [...] Stokes' theorem is a vast generalization of this theorem."

Sine the vector LaPlacian is the 3D generalization of the second derivative, it is rather interesting that Stokes theorem essentially describes the principle of integration in 3D:

"Stokes' theorem says that the integral of a differential form ω over the boundary of some orientable manifold Ω is equal to the integral of its exterior derivative dω over the whole of Ω."

So, this is a generalization of:

"This classical Kelvin–Stokes theorem relates the surface integral of the curl of a vector field **F** over a surface (that is, the flux of curl **F**) in Euclidean three-space to the line integral of the vector field over its boundary (also known as the loop integral)."

That seems to lead to the following:

The surface integral of the curl of a vector field **F** over the boundary surface of some manifold Ω is equal to the volume integral of the derivative of curl **F**, which would be **B**.

But because divergence is also a differential form, it seems one can also write:

The surface integral of the divergence of a vector field F over the boundary surface of some manifold Ω is equal to the volume integral of the derivative of div **F**, which would be **E**.

And since **v** = **E** + **B**, it seems that with some clever math it is possible to compute curl **F** as well as div **F** from **v**, even though **F** itself is undefined in infinitesimal notation and can thus not be computed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks, cleaned it up a bit.